# Points, tags and overlap

Tags: feature-request, tags, security

I noticed that there's a [.net-4](/questions/tagged/.net-4) tag with very little usage (2) and decided to suggest it should be rolled into the [.net-4.0](/questions/tagged/.net-4.0) tag. Needless to say I have no points in this tag.

As the [.net-4.0](/questions/tagged/.net-4.0) is used vastly less than the more common [.net](/questions/tagged/.net) tag, I don't have any points in [.net-4](/questions/tagged/.net-4) either (I do have 46 in [.net](/questions/tagged/.net)).

So... despite having more than enough points in a "super-set" tag, I was unable to make the suggestion.

I'm assuming that SE sites have no concept of related tags but would like to suggest they may be useful. It doesn't have to be a tree; it could simply be a "similarity" or "overlap" weighting between any two tags.

This could be used as a multiplier when calculating whether the user has sufficient points to edit the tag; for example: .net -> 0.2 -> .net-4.

Therefore, when calculating the points for [.net-4](/questions/tagged/.net-4), look at all connected tags and add up `Score * SimilarityWeighting`. In the above example, my [.net-4](/questions/tagged/.net-4) points would be `46 * 0.2 = 9.2` for the purposes of calculating permissions.

Comment: In some ways there shouldn't actually be a .net-4.0 tag, as it's officially called ".NET 4" rather than ".NET 4.0" ... Just a minor point of trivia :)

Comment: @JonSkeet - true, but that's the "marketing" name, it's still technically 4.0 if we're going by assembly major.minor and file version numbers.

Comment: @Kev: If you use assembly major and minor versions, .NET 3.5 is a huge mess, containing (as it does) various 2.0 assemblies etc...

Comment: @jon - oh don't I know it and get where you're coming from. I'm guessing we're going to have this joy all over again with the forthcoming update to 4.0. But I guess there's no harm in calling it 4.0 because there's a tagging consistency there that sits well for me and my karma :)

Comment: There are multiple other posts suggesting ways to inherit or combine reputation across parent/child or related tags.

Comment: @Nemo then please feel free to link them/close as a dupe, but be aware this was raised in 2011...